# \onecolumn is moving the content to a new page

Tags: two-column

I'm writing a document and downloaded a template which I found pretty decent. But I have a problem because it is set to split the text into two columns. When I'm trying to change this with the `\onecolumn` command all the text moves to a new page but the abstract stays.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[fleqn,9pt]{SelfArx} % Document font size and equations flushed left

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Specify a different language here - english by default

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COLUMNS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm} % Distance between the two columns of text
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt} % Width of the border around the abstract

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COLORS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,90} % Color of the article title and sections
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,20,20} % Color of the boxes behind the abstract and headings

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for hyperlinks
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=color2,citecolor=color1,linkcolor=color1,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\JournalInfo{Journal, Vol. XXI, No. 1, 1-5, 2013} % Journal information
\Archive{Additional note} % Additional notes (e.g. copyright, DOI, review/research article)

\PaperTitle{Article Title} % Article title

\Authors{John Smith\textsuperscript{1}*, James Smith\textsuperscript{2}} % Authors
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{1}\textit{Department of Biology, University of Examples, London, United Kingdom}} % Author affiliation
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{2}\textit{Department of Chemistry, University of Examples, London, United Kingdom}} % Author affiliation
\affiliation{*\textbf{Corresponding author}: john@smith.com} % Corresponding author

\Keywords{Keyword1 --- Keyword2 --- Keyword3} % Keywords - if you don't want any simply remove all the text between the curly brackets
\newcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords} % Defines the keywords heading name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\Abstract{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\flushbottom % Makes all text pages the same height

\maketitle % Print the title and abstract box
\onecolumn
\tableofcontents % Print the contents section

\thispagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering from the first page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section*{Introduction} % The \section*{} command stops section numbering

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction} % Adds this section to the table of contents

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Methods}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Results and Discussion}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

%------------------------------------------------
\phantomsection
\section*{Acknowledgments} % The \section*{} command stops section numbering

\end{document}
```

Also the document includes a selfmade class named SelfArx.cls in which the original class article gets modified but I wasn't able two find the line where the splitting is set to redo it.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{SelfArx}[25/01/2012, v1.0]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}      % Needed to pick between latex and pdflatex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{times}      % Loads the Times-Roman Fonts
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % Loads the Times-Roman Math Fonts

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   VARIOUS USEFUL PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[left=2cm,%
right=2cm,%
top=2.25cm,%
bottom=2.25cm,%
headheight=11pt,%
letterpaper]{geometry}%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIGURES AND TABLES CAPTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,small},%
labelsep=period,%
justification=raggedright]{caption}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE HEADER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}  % Needed to define custom headers/footers
\RequirePackage{lastpage}  % Number of pages in the document
\pagestyle{fancy}          % Enables the custom headers/footers
% Headers
\lhead{}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{\small\sffamily\bfseries\@PaperTitle\  --- \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% Footers
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% % No footer rule

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION/SUBSECTION/PARAGRAPH SET-UP
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering\arabic{section}. #1}}}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering#1}}}
  []  
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []    
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1} 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{10pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLEOFCONTENTS SET-UP
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\tocsep} 
\setlength\tocsep{1.5pc} % Sets the indentation of the sections in the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Three levels in the table of contents section: sections, subsections and subsubsections

\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents{subsection}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[\tocsep]
  {\footnotesize\sffamily}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MULTIPLE AUTHOR SET
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

\newcount\@authcnt
\newcount\@tmpcnt\@tmpcnt\z@

\def\@affiliation{%
  \ifnum\@tmpcnt<\@authcnt
   \global\advance\@tmpcnt1
    \raggedright \csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@tmpcnt\endcsname\hfill\\%
   \let\next\@affiliation \vskip1pt
  \else
   \let\next\relax
  \fi
\next}

\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{%
    \global\advance\@authcnt1
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@authcnt\endcsname
    {#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST CONTROL
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

\RequirePackage{enumitem}
%\setlist{nolistsep} % Uncomment to remove spacing between items in lists (enumerate, itemize)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT+AUTHOR FRAME
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

\newcommand{\PaperTitle}[1]{\def\@PaperTitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\Archive}[1]{\def\@Archive{#1}}
\newcommand{\Authors}[1]{\def\@Authors{#1}}
\newcommand{\JournalInfo}[1]{\def\@JournalInfo{#1}}
\newcommand{\Abstract}[1]{\def\@Abstract{#1}}
\newcommand{\Keywords}[1]{\def\@Keywords{#1}}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\twocolumn[{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
\vskip20pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
\vskip10pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}%
\vskip18pt%
\fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
\colorbox{color2!10}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-4\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\ifx\@Keywords\@empty%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract%
\else%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract\\[4pt]%
\textbf{\keywordname}\\\@Keywords%
\fi%
}%
}%
\vskip4pt%
\begingroup%
\raggedright\sffamily\small%
\footnotesize\@affiliation\par%
\endgroup%%
}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}]%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\bfseries\color{color1}\textsuperscript{[#1]}}
%\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0cm}
\let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}%
\oldbibliography{#1}%
\setlength\itemsep{0pt}}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you considered placing the instruction `\onecolumn` either inside the preamble or immediately after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Yes I tried this, but it only work the way I'm expecting it to when I'm placing it after the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `\twocolumn[{%` and the corresponding line `}]%`?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338831/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\maketitle` itself is redefined to split the page, which is why `\onecolumn` has no effect on the document as a whole if issued before this.

Try removing

```
\twocolumn[{%
```

and

```
}]%
```

from the redefinition.

```
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
\vskip20pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
\vskip10pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}%
\vskip18pt%
\fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
\colorbox{color2!10}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-4\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\ifx\@Keywords\@empty%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract%
\else%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract\\[4pt]%
\textbf{\keywordname}\\\@Keywords%
\fi%
}%
}%
\vskip4pt%
\begingroup%
\raggedright\sffamily\small%
\footnotesize\@affiliation\par%
\endgroup%%
}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}
```

Comment: @zzuussee See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338831/