# Unaligned abstract part in template

Tags: abstract

I've recently downloaded a template suiting my flavor. After configuring it myself a little bit a problem ocured. The abstract part is now unaligned with rest of the text.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[fleqn,9pt]{SelfArx} % Document font size and equations flushed left

\usepackage[english]{babel} % Specify a different language here - english by default

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COLORS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,90} % Color of the article title and sections
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,20,20} % Color of the boxes behind the abstract and headings

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for hyperlinks
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=color2,citecolor=color1,linkcolor=color1,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\JournalInfo{Journal, Vol. XXI, No. 1, 1-5, 2013} % Journal information
\Archive{Additional note} % Additional notes (e.g. copyright, DOI, review/research article)

\PaperTitle{Article Title} % Article title

\Authors{John Smith\textsuperscript{1}*, James Smith\textsuperscript{2}} % Authors
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{1}\textit{Department of Biology, University of Examples, London, United Kingdom}} % Author affiliation
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{2}\textit{Department of Chemistry, University of Examples, London, United Kingdom}} % Author affiliation
\affiliation{*\textbf{Corresponding author}: john@smith.com} % Corresponding author

\Keywords{Keyword1 --- Keyword2 --- Keyword3} % Keywords - if you don't want any simply remove all the text between the curly brackets
\newcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords} % Defines the keywords heading name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\Abstract{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\flushbottom % Makes all text pages the same height
\maketitle % Print the title and abstract box

\tableofcontents % Print the contents section

\thispagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering from the first page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section*{Introduction} % The \section*{} command stops section numbering

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction} % Adds this section to the table of contents

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Methods}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Results and Discussion}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

%------------------------------------------------
\phantomsection
\section*{Acknowledgments} % The \section*{} command stops section numbering

\end{document}
```

The above included class is specified with the following code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{SelfArx}[25/01/2012, v1.0]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}      % Needed to pick between latex and pdflatex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{times}      % Loads the Times-Roman Fonts
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % Loads the Times-Roman Math Fonts

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   VARIOUS USEFUL PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[left=0.8cm,%
right=0.8cm,%
top=1.8cm,%
bottom=1.8cm,%
headheight=11pt,%
a4paper]{geometry}%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIGURES AND TABLES CAPTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,small},%
labelsep=period,%
justification=raggedright]{caption}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE HEADER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}  % Needed to define custom headers/footers
\RequirePackage{lastpage}  % Number of pages in the document
\pagestyle{fancy}          % Enables the custom headers/footers
% Headers
\lhead{}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{\small\sffamily\bfseries\@PaperTitle\  --- \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% Footers
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% % No footer rule

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION/SUBSECTION/PARAGRAPH SET-UP
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering\arabic{section}. #1}}}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering#1}}}
  []  
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []    
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1} 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{10pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLEOFCONTENTS SET-UP
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\tocsep} 
\setlength\tocsep{1.5pc} % Sets the indentation of the sections in the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Three levels in the table of contents section: sections, subsections and subsubsections

\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents{subsection}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[\tocsep]
  {\footnotesize\sffamily}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MULTIPLE AUTHOR SET
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

\newcount\@authcnt
\newcount\@tmpcnt\@tmpcnt\z@

\def\@affiliation{%
  \ifnum\@tmpcnt<\@authcnt
   \global\advance\@tmpcnt1
    \raggedright \csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@tmpcnt\endcsname\hfill\\%
   \let\next\@affiliation \vskip1pt
  \else
   \let\next\relax
  \fi
\next}

\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{%
    \global\advance\@authcnt1
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@authcnt\endcsname
    {#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST CONTROL
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

\RequirePackage{enumitem}
%\setlist{nolistsep} % Uncomment to remove spacing between items in lists (enumerate, itemize)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT+AUTHOR FRAME
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

\newcommand{\PaperTitle}[1]{\def\@PaperTitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\Archive}[1]{\def\@Archive{#1}}
\newcommand{\Authors}[1]{\def\@Authors{#1}}
\newcommand{\JournalInfo}[1]{\def\@JournalInfo{#1}}
\newcommand{\Abstract}[1]{\def\@Abstract{#1}}
\newcommand{\Keywords}[1]{\def\@Keywords{#1}}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
\vskip20pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
\vskip10pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}%
\vskip18pt%
\fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
\colorbox{color2!10}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-4\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\ifx\@Keywords\@empty%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract%
\else%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract\\[4pt]%
\textbf{\keywordname}\\\@Keywords%
\fi%
}%
}%
\vskip4pt%
\begingroup%
\raggedright\sffamily\small%
\footnotesize\@affiliation\par%
\endgroup%%
}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}
```

Comment: Your example can't demonstrate the problem as the abstract has no content. Also, please don't both ask a follow-up on an answer to a previous question and ask exactly the same thing as a new question. This just tends to end up with 2 people duplicating each others' efforts and is a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: I immediately removed my follow-up to not create any more havoc. I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem. This place is confusing, I know. The first time I used it, I thought I was leaving a comment and I actually created a second answer by mistake. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation is caused by the paragraph break. I suggest setting `\parindent` to zero inside the scope of `\maketitle{}` as you don't want regular indentation here at all. (I'm assuming.)

Note that `\\` should not be used to insert a line break except in special contexts e.g. `tabular` and `array` environments.

```
\begin{filecontents}{SelfArx.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{SelfArx}[25/01/2012, v1.0]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}

\RequirePackage{times}% package is deprecated and ought not be used
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

\RequirePackage[left=0.8cm,%
right=0.8cm,%
top=1.8cm,%
bottom=1.8cm,%
headheight=11pt,%
a4paper]{geometry}

\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,small},%
labelsep=period,%
justification=raggedright]{caption}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Headers
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\small\sffamily\bfseries\@PaperTitle\  --- \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% Footers
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering\arabic{section}. #1}}}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering#1}}}
  []
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{10pt}

\newlength{\tocsep}
\setlength\tocsep{1.5pc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents{subsection}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[\tocsep]
  {\footnotesize\sffamily}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]

\newcount\@authcnt
\newcount\@tmpcnt\@tmpcnt\z@

\def\@affiliation{%
  \ifnum\@tmpcnt<\@authcnt
   \global\advance\@tmpcnt1
    \raggedright \csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@tmpcnt\endcsname\hfill\\%
   \let\next\@affiliation \vskip1pt
  \else
   \let\next\relax
  \fi
\next}

\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{%
    \global\advance\@authcnt1
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@authcnt\endcsname
    {#1}}

\RequirePackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\PaperTitle}[1]{\def\@PaperTitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\Archive}[1]{\def\@Archive{#1}}
\newcommand{\Authors}[1]{\def\@Authors{#1}}
\newcommand{\JournalInfo}[1]{\def\@JournalInfo{#1}}
\newcommand{\Abstract}[1]{\def\@Abstract{#1}}
\newcommand{\Keywords}[1]{\def\@Keywords{#1}}

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
  \vskip-36pt%
  {\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
  \vskip20pt%
  {\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
  \vskip10pt%
  {\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}%
  \vskip18pt%
  \fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering
      \colorbox{color2!10}{%
        \parbox{\textwidth-4\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
          \ifx\@Keywords\@empty
          \sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\par\@Abstract
          \else
          \sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\par\@Abstract\vskip4pt\par
          \textbf{\keywordname}\par\@Keywords
          \fi
        }%
      }%
      \vskip4pt%
      \begingroup
      \raggedright\sffamily\small
      \footnotesize\@affiliation\par
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
  \vskip25pt%
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[fleqn,9pt]{SelfArx}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,90}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,20,20}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=color2,citecolor=color1,linkcolor=color1,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

\JournalInfo{Journal, Vol. XXI, No. 1, 1-5, 2013}
\Archive{Additional note}

\PaperTitle{Article Title}

\Authors{John Smith\textsuperscript{1}*, James Smith\textsuperscript{2}}
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{1}\textit{Department of Biology, University of Examples, London, United Kingdom}}
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{2}\textit{Department of Chemistry, University of Examples, London, United Kingdom}}
\affiliation{*\textbf{Corresponding author}: john@smith.com}

\Keywords{Keyword1 --- Keyword2 --- Keyword3}
\newcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords}

\Abstract{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding. The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena. Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time. Human reason depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic unity. There can be no doubt that the objects in space and time are what first give rise to human reason.}

\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Introduction}

As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding. The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena. Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time. Human reason depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic unity. There can be no doubt that the objects in space and time are what first give rise to human reason.

As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding. The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena. Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time. Human reason depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic unity. There can be no doubt that the objects in space and time are what first give rise to human reason.


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}

\section{Methods}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Results and Discussion}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

\phantomsection
\section*{Acknowledgments}

\end{document}
```

[image: properly aligned abstract]